# Styled-Components causes "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')" error on server with renderToString

Tags: reactjs, node.js, styled-components

I'm using Styled-Components in component library which is consumed by both a React front end and a server side node API.

The component works fine on the frontend but on the API I get the error:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

when i do the following:

```
  const headerElement = React.createElement(ReportPartComponent, { reportPart: ReportPartEnum.Header, parameters, expressionEvaluator, timeZone: auth.site.timeZone, reportVersion, dataSourcesWithData })
  const header = renderToString(headerElement)
```

As far as I can tell I am using the smame version of React and React DOM everywhere

Comment: please clarify if you are only having issue with ssr?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to render a react component on the server to html before rendering it to a PDF for emailing.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a solution which used styled-components in then end I added this into my component render:

```
 <style>
    {MyStyleSheetString}
 </style>
```